# Google is removing search results related to my name

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a task to rank pages related to my name in the top of SEO, but Google hides the results in accordance with Europe's legislation on privacy and data protection. This means that the main pages that should appear in the search results are located under this link.[image]

Comment: Most likely the reasons for your problem are in your data collection notation or with your privacy policy. Read more https://gdpr.eu/what-is-gdpr/